# spamassassin setup how to make sure X-Spam-Status is allways written

Tags: postfix, spamassassin

I just found out that spamassassin skips checking for email bigger than 250KB by default.
Due to a coding bug, I check for the X-Spam-Status header in incoming emails and did not take into account the fact that it might be null. 
I know that I can increase the size of the limit by configuration but it may cause a load issue on my server.
Since I do not want to redeploy my application at this time I was wondering if there is a way to make sure this header exists automatically in every email, either by spamassassin configuration or by postfix or something else.
Thanks,
Dov.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a setup violates the principles of:

- KISS
- Be liberal in what you accept

You'll be much farther ahead fixing your application rather than relying upon yet another independent piece of code or configuration that you'll need to maintain. Do it the right way.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, it is the "default" setting with spamassasin that it won't scan messages which are bigger than the default/configured size. Without passing the mails through spamd, the "X-Spam-Status" header is not going to be added to the mail, unless you add the header manually to the mail if it is not already present. You can use a pre-processing script to check the header and add it, if the header is not present and then pass that to your application.

Cheers